# Cannot get bytes[] from string

Tags: c#, string, byte, converters

Ok so I had asked a question earlier but I guess it wasnt clear enough.sry guys.
Heres the troubled code

```
        byte data4 = byte.Parse(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        byte data1 = byte.Parse(textBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        byte data2 = byte.Parse(textBox3.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        string Text = "" + textBox1.Text;
        **byte[] b1 = textBox1.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);**
```

Its part of a button_click function in c#.
My goal is to convert a group of textboxes' text into bytes that I can use then to write into the opened file. With the stared code, It always gives an error that the string does not have a definition for encoding. I have the net framework set to 4.5. I hope this makes a little more sense.

Comment: I don't see a file there. Also; string *doesn't* have `Encoding` that is a static member of `System.Text`. Could you clarify how you are trying to encode the bytes?

Comment: It looks like your textboxes are meant to contain hex strings. Is your intent to store the hex values in the file instead of the binary representation of the hex strings? e.g. if the hex string was "A4", should the file contain 1 byte with the value 10100100? Or should it really contain 2 bytes to represent the characters 'A' and '4' (01100101 01010010)? As you can see, there's a big difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the line to:

```
byte[] b1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

As answer above says, this will correct the code

```
byte[] b1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

However if the purpose is for serialization to a file, another option is:

```
// using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
format.Serialize(stream, textBox1.Text);
stream.Close();
```

Then reading

```
Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
text=(string)format.Deserialize(stream); // will throw exception if data is not right
stream.Close();
```